# Preload image PHP and waiting in JS till finished

Tags: php, javascript, image, time

I need a preloader in JS for images. The images are fetched by a PHP script (to avoid opening the file structure to the user) and set as the attribute of the img tag. After the preload we wait for a event bound as an event listener to get fired (kind of like a slideshow).

```
var preloadImage = $('<img />').attr('src', 'getimage.php');
preloadImage.onLoad = function() {console.log('finished')}
```

The problem is, that of course onLoad does not work as it deals with the image being processed in the JS, while in this case we are waiting for the PHP to finish getting the image. The php script is just like this

```
<?php
header("Content-type: image/png");
readfile('image.png');
?>
```

Anyone has an idea how in this case i can make the JS wait till the php has finished loading?

Comment: Set the `onload` handler *before* you set `src`. It will fire after the image is downloaded/fetched from the cache by the browser.

Comment: The browser does not care whether the image is loaded by the web server from the file system or loaded by a web server through php. As long as you set the headers properly, it's all just byte stream. If your JS works when the image is being loaded by the server directly, then it would work when it's being loaded by php. Therefore your php script must be faulty. As you're not giving the full script (you don't even show the `<?php ... ?>` tags, there's no way to tell what's wrong here.

Comment: @LieRyan Ive posted the whole php script, maybe Im doing something wrong here?
DCoder When switching the handler above the, preloadImage is of course undefined or null. When setting it to the selector the onLoad event does not fire.

Comment: maybe you must use collection Image. 
var img = new Image();
img.onload = function() {}
img.src = ... // fire load...

Comment: The logic behind this question is fundamentally flawed - the only load event you are interested in here is the Javascript one. PHP doesn't have to "finish loading" - it's just reading the file from disk and sending it to the client. It is not not caching the image in memory before sending it to the client, it is passing the file system pointer directly through to the network stream. The two "load" events occur at exactly the same time, and the only place you need to handle it is on the client side - in your Javascript.

Comment: @DaveRandom I acknowledge this fact. So in the case with the above given code, does not fire the onLoad event. Any ideas?

Comment: @toxicate20 Well `preloadImage` is a jQuery object and you can't just assign a function to its `onLoad` property, you have to *pass* the function to [`.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/). Try `var preloadImage = $('<img />').attr('src', 'getimage.php').load(function() {console.log('finished')});`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As DaveRandom answered the question perfectly in the discussion above, here is the final code. preloadImage is a jQuery object which means that one needs to pass the .load() function.

```
var preloadImage = $('<img />').attr('src', 'getimage.php').load(function() {console.log('finished')})
```